# What's the difference between ESC/P and ESC/P R? Will python-escpos work with an ESC/P R printer?

Tags: python, escpos

I want to control an Epson printer from Python. The printer is fairly new (from the last 2 years) and so the specifications say that its language is ESC/P R. Is this compatible with ESC/P? The Wikipedia article says ESC/P R is a newer variant of the printer language and it is compatible with ESC/P, but I couldn't find any other sources for this.

And if you're familiar with python-escpos in particular, has python-escpos been known to work with ESC/P R?

Answer (score 2):

The [python-escpos](https://github.com/python-escpos/python-escpos) driver speaks ESC/POS (hence the name), which is different to both ESC/P and ESC/P R.

In particular, python-escpos has no concept of pages, so it is not going to be a useful tool to describe output on an ESC/P printer, even if some of the basic formatting codes are the same.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ESC/P R, but I'm working with an ESC/P printer right now. Neither the python-escpos or escposprinter support all that the printer can do. They may work okay for extremely simple output though (providing you don't need to set fonts, page sizes, etc.); I was able to simply output text formatted by printer defaults with escposprinter.